# When compiling C code in the linux terminal, what is the difference between make <filename> and cc <filename>?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and I understand that both of those commands accomplish the same thing, but does one of them do something different than the other along the way?

Comment: Uh-oh, you really need to read some tutorial on building C source code in Linux... `cc` is a compiler that actually compiles source to executable, `make` is a tool to build complicated programs that require compiling multiple files. While you can do this manually, it's much easier to write a `Makefile` once and then just run `make` each time you wanna build your program.

Comment: I understand that now. This was a question definitely shows my ignorance in C, but I appreciate the detailed answers that were given below.

Comment: Shame on the downvoters for shunning a novice question.  If you don't know where to get started, you have to ask *someone*.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but I also understand the mentality of most users on this website. This website is built around challenging, detailed, researched questions, and much to my chagrin, novice questions don't fit into that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are using `make` then for `hello.c` you will call make as `make hello` and not `make hello.c`. Also, note that `make` is most of the times used with a `Makefile`. Nonetheless, you can build executable binary from single source file using `make` as you have shown.

If the executable (`hello`) does not exist, then both will have same effect - create the executable from source file.

However, if the executable already exists, then `make` will run the build commands only if it thinks that the source code has changed after last build, whereas `cc` will always do the build.

For example:

```
$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
$ make hello
make: 'hello' is up to date.   # make does not think source file has changed
$ touch hello.c                # Update the timestamp of hello.c
$ make hello                   
cc     hello.c   -o hello      # make thinks source file changed. Builds again
$
```

However, `cc` will not check if the source has changed or not. It will always do the required build.

```
$ cc hello.c -o hello
$ ls -l hello | cut -d ' ' -f '8-'    
12:18 hello
$ cc hello.c -o hello                # Build again without changing source
$ ls -l hello | cut -d ' ' -f '8-'
12:21 hello                          # hello was built again
$
```

Above description was for `GNU make` and `GNU cc`. Not sure about other implementations.

**P.S.**: `make` is not a compiler. It only calls the compiler when it thinks it should, as seen in the example above. Whereas `cc` is a compiler.

**P.S.** If you run `cc hello.c`, the excutable is named `a.out`, and not `hello`.

Comment: This make a lot of sense! I didn't know that `make` only works on files that have changed since the previous make. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Jacob Even if the previous `hello` was built by without calling make (i.e. by dirrectly calling `cc`), make will run the build commands (i.e. run `cc` commands) only if it thinks that source file is newer than the the executable.

Answer (score 1):

[`make(1)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is a program that will run commands. You create a file named "Makefile" in a directory. The `Makefile` has a recipe with a specific syntax that is beyond the scope of this answer. You then invoke the `make` command in the directory with the file named `Makefile`

`cc $filename` will invoke a C compiler upon the `$filename`

Comment: Note that make has default rules, so if you have *prog.c*, you can give command *make prog* and it builds it, even if there is no *Makefile*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't understand this topic well, but now I do.

Answer (score 0):

`cc` or `gcc` or `clang` will invoke the compiler.

`make` is used when you have many files to compile.
In `make` you will give name of `.o` file and include header file location.